# Запретить приведение указателя на объект к bool

Tags: c++

Можно запретить компилятору приводить указатель на объект к bool?

```
class A {
}

A* a = nullptr;
if (a) {    // <-- как запретить?
    ...
}
```

Comment: Возможно вам помогут "статический анализатор". Так спасёт разве что warning.

Comment: это валидный код. прям по стандарту. Зачем такое запрещать?

Comment: В проекте было N функций, возвращающих bool. По смыслу - опции. Опции стали сложнее и функции отрефакторил на классы/объекты. В результате код поимел N мест, где вместо проверок на значение опции вызывается проверка на наличие указателя.

Answer (score 1):

Оберните указатель в структуру

```
template<typename T>
struct ptr {
  T* p;
  T& operator*();
  T* operator->();
};
```

Comment: Тогда уж и переопределить `A::operator&` (если можно), и спрятать `new`?